# Android: Run Activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm pretty sure that was asked many times and I researched it a lot. But still stuck with my problem.

I have MainActivity which is launched at Application Start, where I have added a Button on click of which AlertActivity is called.
And when this activity is finished it sets AlertManager which kicks BroadcastReceiver, which on it own side should start AlertActivity again.

Everything works fine except last part, "AlertActivity" didn't start from BroadcastReceiver. No error in logs or console.

I'm using Android 12 (request from customer).

AlertActivity should start from BroadcastReceiver even screen is locked.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet for starting the activity from Receiver?

Comment: Intent AlertIntent = new Intent(_mainContext.getApplicationContext(), AlertActivity.class);
        AlertIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        AlertIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        AlertIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _mainContext.startActivity(AlertIntent);

Comment: Code looks okay, but have you confirmed if onReceive() method of Broadcast receiver is being invoked or not?

Comment: It was, I set breakpoint on line with starActivity(), but another breakpoint on onCreate(0 in AlertActivity never reached.